# Dynamic Script with document.ready() listener not executing with ajax call for cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jquery-events

This is script code of crossdomain. I make ajax call to load this script in my domain but not execute. This can be executed when I put `alert('something')` box in top of `document.ready()` method. See in second code section.

a. first section without alert

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         // .... Some javascript
    });
 </script>
```

b. Second section with alert and its execute.

```
<script>
    alert('something');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // .... Some javascript
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the other domain CORS-enabled? Can you monitor the request? (such as firebug). What kind of request do you send with ajax? (get, post, etc)

Comment: both get and post . only those domain enable which set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with value like htttp://abc.com or * etc ..

Comment: Do you try to monitor the request-response? (like firbug or chrome built-in analyzer). This may help to figure out the exact error or the  actual request-response. It may not help you, but if you share, we may help.

Comment: yes i already test it in firebug also . its completed loaded without error .. there is no problem of request-response ,problem is that script not execute of cross-domain as i put dynamically through ajax in my local-domain page . its execute once i put alert() box at top of the script . i am still find solution . but bad luck ... you have   any idea please help me out on this .. Thanks ...